# Chrome is no longer asking for my password manager re-authentication

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, password-management

Chrome is no longer asking for my password manager re-authentication.
I liked that feature a lot. I tried enabling the feature in `chrome://flags` but I found nothing! I also tried using Google but did not find any useful post.
Is the feature removed? Otherwise how do I enable it?